# What exactly is regarded as 'document read' in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I did find some posts about how pricing is decided, but I want to make it as clear as possible.

Here's my document structure,

```
{
 ...
 firstOption: "A",
 secondOption: "B",
 customerID: "1234",
 ...
}
```

I need to check if any of three conditions is met.

For example, if firstOption is "A", secondOption is "B", or customerID is "1234".

Since Firestore doesn't support `OR` in `where` cluase, my current plan is,

```
db.collection('').get().then(snapshot => snapshot.filter(doc => { 
 const {firstOption, secondOption, customerID} = doc.data();

 if(firstOption === 'A' || secondOption === 'B' || customerID === '1234') 
  return true;
 else 
  return false;    
})
```

If three documents are returned, is it regarded as reading three documents or, since no `where` clause is used to filter, reading the entire documents in the collection?

Comment: You've read all the documents, the filtering is carried out client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write client code that queries a collection and doesn't filter any documents, it will read **every** document in that collection so that the client can access all their snapshots.  In general, if a query matches a document, it will count as a read.